# Azure Synapse SQL: Security option for SQLOnDemand

Tags: azure-synapse

SQL On Demand

Is Daynamic Data Masking, Row Level Security & RBAC(or Role based) applicable to SQL On Demand Queries or data access from NoteBooks ?

Any links to official document confirming that ?

Answer (score 2):

SQL on demand is a service for exploring files in your data lake, so only offers a limited T-SQL surface area.  More advanced options such as Dynamic Data Masking and Row-Level Security (RLS) are not available, as at today.  You can see the T-SQL features listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview#t-sql-support) and it does clearly state: "DML functionality is currently not supported."

The security model is pretty simple, and you access files using either Azure Active Directory (AAD) pass-through or SAS credentials.  The current suggestion is to use SAS for performance as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-sql-on-demand#azure-ad-pass-through-performance).

In terms of notebooks, SQL on demand is in theory just a SQL endpoint so you should be able to connect with any client that supports that.  You can definitely connect from Azure Data Studio, which offers a notebook experience:

[image: Azure Data Studio SQL-on-demand connection]

The service is currently in preview so I think it will improve and add more features as it goes along - look out for GA.

HTH